# Plotting multiple lines in plotly on the same graph using fig.show?

Tags: python, flask, plotly

I have some old code that graphs lots of lines on the same graph in a manner like

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

data = [regtimes, avg5times]
py.iplot(data, filename='basic-line')
```

and this would graph both lines on the same plot. I tried to use this again and it says plotly.plotly is deprecated. Now I have something like

```
        individualtimes = go.Scatter(

            y = times,
            x = x1,

        )

        test = go.Scatter(
            y2=[1, 1, 5],
            x2=x1
        )

        data = [individualtimes,test]
        fig = go.Figure(data=data)
        fig.show()
```

Is there a way to use fig.show to graph multiple lines like this? Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I have found the answer! It has been changes to use add_trace and then show the figure. Plotly uses

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Create random data with numpy
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

N = 100
random_x = np.linspace(0, 1, N)
random_y0 = np.random.randn(N) + 5
random_y1 = np.random.randn(N)
random_y2 = np.random.randn(N) - 5

# Create traces
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=random_x, y=random_y0,
                    mode='lines',
                    name='lines'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=random_x, y=random_y1,
                    mode='lines+markers',
                    name='lines+markers'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=random_x, y=random_y2,
                    mode='markers', name='markers'))

fig.show()
```

The rest of this can be found [here](https://plot.ly/python/line-charts/).